# How to make Ubuntu 32 bit read my 4GB RAM on a Acer Travelmate 3210 notebook?

Tags: memory-usage

I have Acer Travelmate 3210 notebook with 4GB RAM, but after I install Ubuntu 32bit Desktop, Ubuntu says my RAM is only 2GB.

How to make Ubuntu use all my RAM? My notebook doesn't seem to support Ubuntu 64 bit.

Comment: Do you have any other operating systems installed? Can they see the additional RAM?

Answer (score 3):

You can try to enable or install PAE enabled kernel. If you are running Ubuntu 12.04, it should have automatically installed the pae kernel, if it has detected more than 3gb of RAM.

You can also enable it manually, please follow the instructions from this [Ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnablingPAE/) page.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Acer's website](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/TravelMate3210/TravelMate3210sp2.shtml), the maximum amount of memory supported by your model is 2GB:

> RAM / Max RAM: 256Mb or 512MB / 2GB DDR2-533

Comment: Now, that's arguably the best answer one can give - Blame the hardware!! LOL...

Comment: I think you are seeing the spec of an older model. If he is saying it is 4Gb ram, the link you have clearly says that the computer is of 2Gb ram.

Comment: @ForbiddenOverseer: ROFL!

Comment: He could have upgrade memory manually beyond the specs, and the device is simply ignoring the additional bar. So as George suggested, checking whether other OSses can see all the RAM is a valid request. @rico: you could also let us know if your notebook shipped with 4GB or you upgraded yourself, to make things clear.